# Adding a Log In using Salesforce button

Tags: apex, rest-api, oauth2, authentication, connected-apps

I am building a web application that will read/write data from a user's salesforce org.  Is there any way to put a button on my site that says "Login with Salesforce" and when clicked, it would trigger some OAuth / Authentication flow where I would get an access token and then could make only API calls on behalf of the user?

I do not have a way of creating connected apps within other user's salesforce org so looking to see if there is an alternate way to achieve the above?

My goal is for any user who has a salesforce account that they would be able to log in this way and I would be able to retrieve the token and access whatever data in salesforce that their user account has access to via REST APIs

I would like to do this without the user sending a post request with their username/password on my side.  I am not hoping to store or see this data.

This would be similar to how some sites allow you to log in with your Twitter or Facebook credentials.

I found this link on the salesforce site which looks promising, but I am not sure if this will work.  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5

Comment: It is possible for you to initiate the oAuth flow in the way that you describe but you're going to need to set up a Connected App so that you've got a client id which identifies your app/service and so that the user can grant you access to their Salesforce data. You should be very specific in your scope on the connected app definition and only request access to the bare minimum of the user's data.

Comment: You'll need a connected app and you want OpenID Connect: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_create_openid_connect.htm&type=5